# My app works in local put it crash in heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm new in Ruby on Rails but I was able to upload others apps in Heroku. However has been a while trying to run this one and I can't figure out what is going on.

My repo www.github.com/pocasluces/LibreTeka-from-BookShare

When I push to heroku everything looks to works, but when I go to the URL it show the error "Application Error. An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details". As you see here.

```
-----> Using set buildpack heroku/ruby
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.1.5
-----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.11.2
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
   Using rake 11.1.1
   Using i18n 0.7.0
   Using json 1.8.3
   Using minitest 5.8.4
   Using thread_safe 0.3.5
   Using builder 3.2.2
   Using erubis 2.7.0
   Using mini_portile2 2.0.0
   Using rack 1.6.4
   Using mime-types 2.99.1
   Using arel 6.0.3
   Using request_store 1.3.0
   Using ffi 1.9.10
   Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.1
   Using dynamic_form 1.1.4
   Using tilt 2.0.2
   Using httpclient 2.7.1
   Using isbn 2.0.10
   Using json_pure 1.8.3
   Using pg 0.18.4
   Using bundler 1.11.2
   Using thor 0.19.1
   Using rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.5
   Using rails_stdout_logging 0.0.5
   Using texticle 1.0.4.20101004123327
   Using tzinfo 1.2.2
   Using nokogiri 1.6.7.2
   Using mail 2.6.3
   Using rack-test 0.6.3
   Using sprockets 3.5.2
   Using ffi-compiler 0.1.3
   Using haml 4.0.7
   Using rails_12factor 0.0.3
   Using activesupport 4.2.6
   Using loofah 2.0.3
   Using scrypt 2.1.1
   Using rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
   Using globalid 0.3.6
   Using activemodel 4.2.6
   Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.3
   Using rails-dom-testing 1.0.7
   Using activerecord 4.2.6
   Using protected_attributes 1.1.3
   Using activejob 4.2.6
   Using actionview 4.2.6
   Using authlogic 3.4.6
   Using isbn_validation 1.2.2
   Using actionpack 4.2.6
   Using actionmailer 4.2.6
   Using railties 4.2.6
   Using sprockets-rails 3.0.4
   Using rails 4.2.6
   Using rails3-generators 1.0.0
   Using themes_for_rails 0.5.1
   Bundle complete! 15 Gemfile dependencies, 54 gems now installed.
   Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
   Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
   Bundle completed (0.38s)
   Cleaning up the bundler cache.
   Detected manifest file, assuming assets were compiled locally
-----> Discovering process types
   Procfile declares types     -> web
   Default types for buildpack -> console, rake, worker
-----> Compressing...
   Done: 29.4M
-----> Launching...
   Released v20
   https://libre-teka.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

Heroku logs show the following error:

```
2016-03-31T18:31:06.971531+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-03-31T18:31:10.042084+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server thin -p 58311 -e production`
2016-03-31T18:31:15.453858+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require': cannot load such file -- thin (LoadError)
2016-03-31T18:31:15.453884+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
2016-03-31T18:31:15.453886+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
2016-03-31T18:31:15.453886+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
2016-03-31T18:31:15.453903+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
2016-03-31T18:31:15.453899+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `const_get'
2016-03-31T18:31:15.453893+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2016-03-31T18:31:15.453899+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `block in get'
2016-03-31T18:31:15.453903+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:75:in `start'
2016-03-31T18:31:15.453900+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `inject'
2016-03-31T18:31:15.453900+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `each'
2016-03-31T18:31:15.453902+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:290:in `server'
2016-03-31T18:31:15.453902+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:125:in  `print_boot_information'
2016-03-31T18:31:15.453901+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `get'
2016-03-31T18:31:15.453904+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
2016-03-31T18:31:15.453904+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
2016-03-31T18:31:15.453905+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2016-03-31T18:31:15.453906+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2016-03-31T18:31:15.453912+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
2016-03-31T18:31:15.453913+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2016-03-31T18:31:15.495891+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2016-03-31T18:31:16.625911+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-03-31T18:31:16.659446+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-03-31T19:21:49.822163+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=libre-teka.herokuapp.com request_id=94c6b60b-5d8f-4159-886f-8c98f9091399 fwd="2.155.140.190" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

but `heroku run rails console` run without problems.

```
Running rails c on libre-teka.... up, run.6894
Loading production environment (Rails 4.2.6)
irb(main):001:0>
```

My database .yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3
test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000  
production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.postgresql
```

Any sugestions?

pd: Sorry for my english.

Comment: Have you run your database migrations on Heroku? `heroku run rake db:migrate`

Comment: Yes, I did. Also I try a `pg:reset`

Comment: can you check your db yml file and make sure you are using postgres?

Comment: I compare it with other proyects and it is the same in production. I attach it just in case I miss something.

Comment: `tail` the rails logs themselves to see the actual error.

Comment: logs tail added. I'm adding everything in the questions I think there are a lot of information in it if there are a better way to post it just let me know. I'm also new in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

From the output of `bundle install` it doesn't look like the `thin` gem is actually included in the `:production` group within your Gemfile or at the top level of your Gemfile.

```
group :production do
  gem 'thin'
end
```

Adding it and redeploying should fix the issue.